# Is something "sudden" also unexpected?

Tags: disambiguation

As I understand the word "sudden" (or "suddenly") it indicates a rapid change, usually without prior notification that the event was about to occur.
I find it hard to find sources for the second half of my statement, but I also find it difficult to create an example without an element of surprise.

Is a sudden event always surprising/unexpected?
(The event may have been predictable in general, but not for this specific moment)

---

Please note if I have a misunderstanding in the following examples, or provide one for either a slow or an expected sudden event if it exists;

*Suddenly he walked on the street* (instead of indicating and then walking).
It was likely expected that he will cross the street at some point, but not this very instant.

*Suddenly he started to rise from the couch.*
Obviously he couldn't sit there for all eternity, but there was no indication he would start now (the actual rising might still be slow and "un-sudden").

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/suddenly) defines suddenly as "quickly and unexpectedly" although I'm not convinced.

Comment: When I flip this switch there will be a sudden inrush of water.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word “sudden” does not indicate “surprising” or “unexpected” except in so far as that naturally goes along with the quality of being abrupt. In many cases, something that is sudden may have an element of surprise because the event itself does not take a long time to get going. But if there happens to be some way to predict it with high accuracy, that doesn’t mean it is not sudden. For example, you could say that during a solar eclipse, the sky “suddenly” gets darker. This is no less true for someone who knows exactly when the eclipse is expected to happen based on detailed astronomical information.

Answer (score 3):

It would be unexpected only if someone was expecting something else. But someone's expectations are not included in the semantic meaning of "suddenly." So, suddenly does not imply unexpectedness.